# Migrating a module written in Swift 3.0 to Swift 2.3?

Tags: ios, swift, module, migration, cocoapods

The company I currently work for supports legacy products written in Swift 2.3 (I don't agree with it). At the moment they currently want to continue rolling out features supporting the legacy version and thus, I'm currently in a bind concerning a pod written in Swift 3.0.

I attempted to convert the syntax back to Swift 2.3 by installing Xcode 7.3.1 with the intention of hopefully migrating that code. Unfortunately, since it's a module written in Swift 3.0 my efforts were futile.

I'm out of suggestions though I'm not opposed to writing the code in the module in Swift 2.3 however I know I'll be looking at a tedious process for the long run. What steps should I take to migrate a module written in the most updated version of Swift back to version 2.3?

Comment: Does the pod you're trying to access have an older version for Swift 2? For instance, I accidentally used an old version of Alamofire designed for Swift 2.3 in a project that I was setting up dependencies for, and I got the old version of AF because I copied some old code about the version in my Podfile. I believe if the old module exists you can still access it.

Comment: @Pierce No, it does not. It was written in Swift 3.0. I try to look for pods that have an older version available but this pod seems to not have it at all. I did make sure to contact the contributor of the repository and they did offer to write one in Swift 2.3 but I'm afraid that might not be a feasible thing for them + I don't really expect them to anyone. I want to try to maneuver this obstacle in the best way I can as it's literally the only pod available that can meet a significant requirement in a project I'm working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you can use Xcode 8 to do this. Select each of your schemes and then set 'use legacy swift version' in build settings to yes. Compile and then run. Swift will start presenting lots of errors. For example, this code (in swift 3):

```
SKAction.rotate(byAngle: CGFloat(M_PI_2), duration: 10)
```

is

```
SKAction.rotateByAngle: CGFloat(M_PI_2), duration: 10)
```

in swift 2. You have to manually fix all the errors that swift says, so you need a clear understanding of the old swift syntax.

Comment: So are you saying that I can the aforementioned to the pod that has the Swift 3.0 syntax and attempt to migrate it in Swift 2.3 by changing the boolean for the legacy version in the build settings and proceed to fix each individual error? It's bound to be a tedious process for sure but worth a shot. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can do that if you want to support legacy swift

Comment: It's not as I'm still kind of struggling with a few things. Migrating this module I'm working on to Swift 2.3 may be rendered as impossible due to some sytax add-ons in Swift 3 that may not be translatable in Swift 2.3. So while your answer might be correct, it also may be circumstantial. @paper1111

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. Swift 2.2 introduced  something like `#if swift(>=2.3)
/* this compiles on Xcode 8 / Swift 2.3 / iOS 10 */
#else
/* this compiles on Xcode 7 / Swift 2.2 / iOS 9 */
#endif` though, it can make features unavailable to swift 2.3 available to people using swift 3, and is a compromise. See [here](https://swift.org/blog/swift-2-2-new-features/).